# How to see in ASP.NET from which page was a method called?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a ASP.NET MVC project in which I have a method on a controller which is being called from two separate pages, until now the behaviour was the same but now I need it to be slightly different I just need to see if I'm on page A or page B so I know which behaviour happens.

Is there any solution with the `ViewData` or `View` or something else with which I can check from which page this method was called?

Comment: Would it not be easier to pass a control variable indicating page 1/2 or functionality 1,2,3.. etc to this controller method ?

Comment: I thought of that but I'm a bit wary because I'm not supposed to change page A or B, not even to change the query string or etc so I was hoping there was something which can be done only on the method side.

Comment: Got it. Check if this previous SO answer can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529265/asp-net-mvc-finding-out-the-caller-to-a-method-when-modelstate-isvalid

Comment: HttpContext.Request.Url may provide you the source path

Comment: Check this answer - use Request.UrlReferrer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471188/how-do-i-get-the-referrer-url-in-an-asp-net-mvc-action

Comment: Could you guys please convert your comments to question so I can upvote them and mark one as the correct answer, actually both `HttpContext.Request.Url` and `Request.UrlRefferer` work.