# ASP.NET MVC: How do I output the Controller and View that is currently being rendered?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, routes

I have a complicated set of routes and I need to edit a specific web page.  Given a URL, how do I determine which controller and view created that page?

I'm open to using ASP.NET MVC to write the information directly to the page where textcolor== background color, or anything else you may recommend.

I'd like a solution that I can use in production (where the MVC route debugger is disabled)

Comment: Where do you want to use this data? If you want to display it in your view, then you already know which View that "created that page".

Comment: @Dismissile I'll be placing this within my site.master page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access the controller and action directly through the `ViewContext`.

```
// ASP.Net MVC 3
ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("controller").RawValue
ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("action").RawValue

// ASP.Net MVC 2 and below:
ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider["controller"].RawValue
ViewContext.Controller.ValueProvider["action"].RawValue
```

To get the view, have a look at this [answer to a similar question by Phil Haack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268763/retrieve-the-current-view-name-in-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: Alternately: ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"] and ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"]

Comment: OP asked to know the Controller and View that created the page...I'm not sure if this is a typo and he wanted Controller and Action or if he needs to know the View as well.

Comment: @Dismissile yes, you're right. I didn't realize OP needed the view as well. Updated my post accordingly.