# HtmlHelper extension to find view name

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper

I'm trying to create a `HtmlExtension` to retrieve the name of the current view.

However, I don't want to have the requested view (e.g. "LogOn" for "/Account/LogOn") but the actual file that is being processed (e.g. `"_Layout"`).

The closest I could find was `html.ViewDataContainer.ToString()` which returns `{ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Layout_cshtml}` for example, but I don't think that parsing this would be a great idea.

Is this information available in the Html Extension?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you had a chance to look at this post? http://stackoverflow.com/q/1268763/1437962

Comment: yes, but it gives the controller action instead of the view name/path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an extension like this,

```
public static string ViewName(this WebViewPage page)
{
  return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(page.VirtualPath);
}
```

then from a razor view,

```
The view name is: @this.ViewName()
```

or without extension,

```
The view name is: @Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(VirtualPath)
```