# Is it possible to RenderPartial a default or error View if the specified View is not found?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC3.

I am wondering whether it is possible to render an error View if the specified View is absent.

ie if "MyTableX" is absent:

```
RenderPartial("MyTableX");
```

would return "Error.cshtml" as the Partial View, saying something like "Partial View not found" in the page.

Comment: would you be willing to use a partial with child action instead of RenderPartial?

Comment: Certainly, open to expert suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something based off of this - the trick is in getting the view path.
A missing view returns an InvalidOperationException. So we really need to determine if the view is missing or if it's caused from something different. One way is to figure out how to get the IView in the filter, cast it to a RazorView and grab the path off of it - or the 'hacky' way is to do the below code, but actually look for "the view" and "was not found" in the exceptions message. Its ugly, I know, but if you want something that works tonight, thats all I got before I head to bed, otherwise try to get the view info from that filter.

This code from Phil Haack in this link may help in trying to get the path name, a quick test yielded I wasn't able to get the IView because my filterContext.ParentActionViewContext was null.
[Retrieve the current view name in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268763/retrieve-the-current-view-name-in-asp-net-mvc)

So I wrote this basic one, but again, anything throwing an InvalidOperationException will cause this.

Also note a missing 'MissingView.cshtml" could cause an infinite loop here (untested assumption)

```
 [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
    public class ViewCheckFilterAttribute : FilterAttribute, IExceptionFilter
    {
        public void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
        {
            var exception = filterContext.Exception;
            if (exception is System.InvalidOperationException)
            {
                //ideally here we check to ensure view doesn't exist as opposed
                //to something else raising this exception
                filterContext.Result = new ViewResult
                {
                    ViewName = "~/Views/Shared/MissingView.cshtml"
                };
                filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

MVC got an attribute called [HandleError] which you should set on your BaseController (or on each controller). There is no need to specify any of the options for the attribute.

The problem with [HandleError] is that it can’t handle 404 (not found), thus we need to create a custom error controller and tell ASP.NET to use it (by configuring web.config and creating and ErrorController):

http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/11/how-to-handle-errors-in-asp-net-mvc/#.UTknoxyfjmA

Comment: I think this approach only redirects the user rather than replacing a partial view with a default. Am I wrong?

Comment: Yes Dave it works for Full page view.As he asked I am wondering whether. it is possible to render an error View if the specified View is absent.

Comment: it's a good link to share. And yes it's possible. But may involve more work than he wants to do.

Comment: Hi Folks, Thanks for these comments. While I appreciate the link and is good learning, I was rather hoping for a straight default View. One would think one could put it somewhere in web.config. In effect if View not found display default "Alternative View". Perhaps it is not possible, and one needs to build a more comprehensive error handler as described in the link.

Comment: @EdB, this is possible with slightly different means. If, for example, you rendered your partial with a child Html.Action Method, you could accomplish this a couple ways.

Comment: I'm not at my comp now but think this can be done with a custom global action filter ... Not having to rely on handle error. Ill check it out shorty.