# How can I know in the controller which partial view made a callback

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, callback, devexpress

I have two partial views that has the same model, I am using devexpress callbacks.
My question is if I can know in my controller function which partial view made the callback and then render it? Or I need to duplicate the function and just render in each function the correct partial view?

Comment: I don't know if devExpress makes it difficult, but can you add a property to the viewmodel that you can put a unique value into? Render it to a hidden field in the view and then examine the property in the controller to see which view you are receiving.

Comment: I don't understand how to do it can you add code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view returns to you only that you pass into it. So, you should pass your view-name into the hidden field container, as an example, and then read this value from the server side.  Someone already answered [how to pass view name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268763/retrieve-the-current-view-name-in-asp-net-mvc/1278899#1278899), I will try to extend this answer.

First of all, you need to create some view-path parsing extension

```
public static class IViewExtensions
{
    public static string GetViewName(this IView view)
    {
        string viewUrl = String.Empty;
        if (view is BuildManagerCompiledView)
        {
            viewUrl = ((BuildManagerCompiledView)view).ViewPath;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Buld manager is not defined!");
        }

        string viewFileName = viewUrl.Substring(viewUrl.LastIndexOf('/'));
        string viewFileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(viewFileName);
        return (viewFileNameWithoutExtension);
    }
}
```

Then pass your each view-names into the form container

```
@using ViewExtensionNamespace;
<input type="hidden" id="ViewName" name="ViewName" value="@Html.ViewContext.View.GetViewName()" />
```

And read it from the server side

```
 name = Request.Params["ViewName"];
```

Comment: I try it now it tells me who is the controller and what action, but I want the partial view name that call that function...

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand you question the first time properly. I provided some another way