# Any way to check which View the user is on?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

What I am trying to do is, add a button on my nav bar if the user is on a certain page (view).

I set my nav bar in my _Layout.cshtml

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index" class="navbar-brand">bethany's Pie Shop</a></li>
    <li><a asp-controller="Feedback" asp-action="Index">Feedback</a></li>
</ul>
```

So something like @IfUser is on Details view, add this list item.

Other answers don't seem to work in .netcore 2.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268763/retrieve-the-current-view-name-in-asp-net-mvc you could have a look at this question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve the current view name in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268763/retrieve-the-current-view-name-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: In my humble opinion, it is not a duplicate, because it is an ASP.NET core quetsion, because the question doesn't care about passing the viewname to the view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Razor view, just access  :

```
@this.Path
```

This will provide Something like :

```
~/Views/MailBox/Index.cshtml
```

If the code is in a layout file, to access the page, just write :

```
@this.ViewContext.View.Path
```

Then you can compare with a given view easily

Comment: Is the `this` required? Isn't `@Path` enough?

Comment: Sure Path is enough. But it seemed obvious that writing this would show Path is a Page property